# Billing Information Required for App Updates

Tags: ipad, applications, ios-appstore, billing

I'm trying to update 3 apps on my iPad and 3 things happen that never usually happen.

1. It asks me to sign in.
2. It asks for my billing information.
3. My card gets denied.

Now I know my card still works fine so that isn't the problem. The same thing happens when I try to install previously downloaded apps (that cloud button) or install new free apps.

I have no outstanding payments (is it even possible to have outstanding payments with Apple?) so why is this happening?

In case it's needed, I'm using an iPad Air running the latest version. 16GB Harddrive and Wi-Fi only.

I should also make it clear that "None" isn't an option for payment.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, you should probably engage Apple's official App Store support to verify your account / get advice how to make things right.

- https://support.apple.com/itunes
- https://support.apple.com/contact

The former usually has a more direct link to App Store support and you can usually tap links on iOS as well or use the iOS support app which is a free download (but not likely to work if your account is locked)

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-support/id1130498044?mt=8

Lastly, Twitter and Facebook have official Apple Support presence if you like social media to engage, but unless your situation is covered in a knowledge base, they will steer you to official support if you need personal attention and the FAQ aren't helping you fix your error condition with your account or setup.

Answer (score 0):

Apple App Store accepts only **International Credit Cards.** I experienced the same issue when I used a debit card on my iTunes account.

Do check that your credit card is authorized by your bank for international usage.

Also check that your credit card platform is either **Visa/MasterCard/American Express**. Diners' Club and Discover may not work everywhere.

Comment: My card had always been connected successfully. Just one day it decided not to work. I ended up fixing this problem by temporarily changing to another card then back.